# How can get configurable product with associated products?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, associate-products

I want to get configurable product with associated my code is below when I try to get **2 0r 3  configuration product** with associated not get configuration product related simple product properly suggest me how can possible?

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("../app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$result_array = array();
$result_array_listproduct = array();
// $result_array_associated = array();
$product_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                  ->load();
foreach ($product_collection as $product) {
     $ids[] = $product->getId();
}
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($ids);
// exit();
for($i=0;$ids[$i];$i++){
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($ids[$i]); 
echo $product_visi=$_product->getVisibility();

if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){

    $result_array_listproduct["product_id"]=$product_id=$_product->getId(); // product id 
    $result_array_listproduct["product_name"]=$product_name=$_product->getName(); //product name 
    $result_array_listproduct["product_image"]=$product_image=$_product->getImageUrl(); //product's image url
    $result_array_listproduct["product_small_image"]=$product_small_image=$_product->getSmallImageUrl(); //product's small image url
    $result_array_listproduct["product_thumbnail_image"]=$product_thumbnail_image=$_product->getThumbnailUrl(); //product's thumbnail image url  
    $result_array_listproduct["product_regular_price"]=$product_regular_price=$_product->getPrice(); //product's regular Price
    $result_array_listproduct["product_special_price"]=$product_special_price=$_product->getSpecialPrice(); 
    $result_array_listproduct["product_short_description"]=$product_short_description=$_product->getShortDescription(); //product's short description
    $result_array_listproduct["product_long_description"]=$product_long_description=htmlentities($_product->getDescription()); // product's long description
    $result_array_listproduct["product_qty"]=$product_qty=$_product->getStockItem()->getQty();// get product Qty
    $result_array_listproduct["product_attribute"]=$product_attribute=$_product->getAttributeText('color'); // get product attribute color 
    $result_array_listproduct["product_type"]=$product_type=$_product->getTypeId();
    $result_array_listproduct["product_visi"]=$product_visi=$_product->getVisibility();

    //print_r($result_array_listproduct);

    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
    foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["product_id"]= $simple_product->getId(); 
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["product_name"]=$simple_product->getName(); 
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["product_image"]=$simple_product->getImageUrl(); 
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["product_small_image"]=$simple_product->getSmallImageUrl(); 
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["product_thumbnail_image"]=$simple_product->getThumbnailUrl(); 
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["product_regular_price"]=$simple_product->getPrice(); 
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["product_special_price"]=$simple_product->getSpecialPrice(); 
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["sku"]=$simple_product->getSku(); 
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["product_short_description"]=$simple_product->getShortDescription();
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["product_long_description"]=htmlentities($simple_product->getDescription());
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["product_attribute"]=$simple_product->getStockItem()->getQty();
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["product_attribute"]=$simple_product->getAttributeText('color');
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["product_type"]=$simple_product->getTypeId();
        $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]["visibility"]= $simple_product->getVisibility();
            //echo "<pre>";
            //print_r($result_array_listproduct["asociated"]);

        array_push($result_array_listproduct,$result_array_listproduct["asociated"]);


    }

    array_push($result_array, $result_array_listproduct);
}
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result_array);
?>
```

Comment: Great work i have checked your given api :)

Answer (score 1):

finally I got solution long time searching relate and code is below

```
error_reporting(0);
include("../app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$result_array = array();
$result_array_listproduct = array();
$result_array_associated = array();
$product_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                  ->load();
foreach ($product_collection as $product) {
     $ids[] = $product->getId();
}
// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($ids);
// exit();
for($i=0;$ids[$i];$i++){



$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($ids[$i]);

$product_visi=$_product->getVisibility();

if($product_visi == "4"){

    $result_array_listproduct["product_id"]=$product_id=$_product->getId(); // product id 
    $result_array_listproduct["product_name"]=$product_name=$_product->getName(); //product name 
    $result_array_listproduct["product_image"]=$product_image=$_product->getImageUrl(); //product's image url
    $result_array_listproduct["product_small_image"]=$product_small_image=$_product->getSmallImageUrl(); //product's small image url
    $result_array_listproduct["product_thumbnail_image"]=$product_thumbnail_image=$_product->getThumbnailUrl(); //product's thumbnail image url  
    $result_array_listproduct["product_all_images"]=$product_all_image=array();


        //$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
        $images='';
        foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
                $images[]=$image->getUrl();

        } 
        array_push($result_array_listproduct["product_all_images"],$images);


    $result_array_listproduct["product_regular_price"]=$product_regular_price=$_product->getPrice(); //product's regular Price
    $result_array_listproduct["product_special_price"]=$product_special_price=$_product->getSpecialPrice(); 
    $result_array_listproduct["sku"]=$sku=$_product->getSku(); 
    $result_array_listproduct["product_short_description"]=$product_short_description=htmlentities(preg_replace('/"/',' ',$_product->getShortDescription())); //product's short description
    $result_array_listproduct["product_long_description"]=$product_long_description=htmlentities(preg_replace('/"/',' ',$_product->getDescription())); // product's long description
    $result_array_listproduct["product_qty"]=$product_qty=$_product->getStockItem()->getQty();// get product Qty
    $result_array_listproduct["product_attribute"]=$product_attribute=$_product->getAttributeText('color'); // get product attribute color 
    $result_array_listproduct["product_type"]=$product_type=$_product->getTypeId();
    $result_array_listproduct["product_status"]=$product_status=$product->getStatus();
    $result_array_listproduct["product_visi"]=$product_visi=$_product->getVisibility();
    $result_array_listproduct["asociated"]= array();
    //print_r($result_array_listproduct);

    if($product_type=="configurable"){
        $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
        $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
        foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
            $result_array_associated["product_id"]= $simple_product->getId(); 
            $result_array_associated["product_name"]=$simple_product->getName(); 
            $result_array_associated["product_image"]=$simple_product->getImageUrl(); 
            $result_array_associated["product_small_image"]=$simple_product->getSmallImageUrl(); 
            $result_array_associated["product_thumbnail_image"]=$simple_product->getThumbnailUrl(); 
            $result_array_associated["product_regular_price"]=$simple_product->getPrice(); 
            $result_array_associated["product_special_price"]=$simple_product->getSpecialPrice(); 
            $result_array_associated["sku"]=$simple_product->getSku(); 
            $result_array_associated["product_short_description"]=htmlentities(preg_replace('/"/',' ',$simple_product->getShortDescription()));
            $result_array_associated["product_long_description"]=htmlentities(preg_replace('/"/',' ',$simple_product->getDescription()));
            $result_array_associated["product_qty"]=$simple_product->getStockItem()->getQty();
            $result_array_associated["product_attribute"]=$color=$simple_product->getAttributeText('color');
            //$result_array_associated["option_id"]= $simple_product->getResource()->getAttribute("color")->getSource()->getOptionId($color);
            $result_array_associated["option_id"]= $simple_product->getResource()->getAttribute(92)->getSource()->getOptionId($color);
            $result_array_associated["product_type"]=$simple_product->getTypeId();
            $result_array_associated["product_status"]=$simple_product->getStatus();
            $result_array_associated["visibility"]= $simple_product->getVisibility();

            //echo "<pre>";
            //print_r($result_array_listproduct["asociated"]);

            array_push($result_array_listproduct["asociated"],$result_array_associated);

        }

    }
    array_push($result_array, $result_array_listproduct);

}
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result_array);
//echo json_encode($result_array);
```